# How to set the buildDir for cordova android project

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin

I was wondering if cordova has the ability to configure the buildDir for an android project via gradle.properties or build-extras.gradle.

Currently, the way the project is structure I hit the limit of 240 character for file path and need to resolve it.  Trying to following the suggestion in this link: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters/

However, I generate the platform everytime, so I want to find a way to configure the buildDir vs. modifying the generated code.

I've been looking at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle but i'm not seeing any properties that allows for this.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Have you got a solution for this?

Comment: @Moe Sorry, I wasn't able to get this to work and just moved on.